# WinRAR context menu's "Extract here" does not work in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uac, winrar

I recently installed Windows 7 Ultimate on my laptop and I am the administrative user. I have also installed WinRAR.

Whenever I try to extract a RAR file using the 'Extract Here' option from the Explorer context menu, it doesn't work. I am however able to extract by opening the RAR file and then using the Extract option in the tool bar.

It seems that Windows UAC is blocking WinRAR's context menu operation. How can I fix this so I can use the context menu?

Comment: Did you solved it ? i am having the same problem, the answer here didnt worked.

Comment: @Pheonix I uninstalled the version that was installed. Got the latest version from WinRAR site. That solved the problem. It was problem with the installer I had and not with Windows 7

Comment: Since downloading the latest version solved your problem please accept the provided answer. Alternatively you can provide your own answer, preferably with a few details, and accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try the latest version of [Winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) or
- Use an alternative free extraction utility, such as [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)
- If none of above works for you, then just [disable UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off) (although that's not recommended, it's the first thing I do when I install Windows 7. Mainly because the number of problems it causes are much more than the benefit it provides.)

Comment: Personal opinion of UAC is of limited (at best) benifit to the question.

Comment: @edusysadmin That's why it is the last suggestion. I know that the problem should be solved on the application side (they shouldn't ask for admin privileges when it's not necessary). So if the developers of Winrar care about UAC they will update their software accordingly. If not, the user can use an alternative application. However it has been almost 5 years since the introduction of UAC and if users are still having problems with it then disabling it becomes a reasonable act rather than a "personal opinion".

Comment: Because I enforce UAC for my users, I enforce (as high as possible) UAC for myself and don't run into the issues you express.  Again your reasonable action statement is an opinion rooted in how you decide to run your computer.

Comment: Not everybody use their computer the same way. The lowest option of UAC (i.e. disabling it) says "Choose this only if you make changes to the Windows settings and/or you need to use programs that are not certified for Win 7..." Yes, me and many other people (at least the OP here) use such software/games. And we, super users, do change Windows settings. Disabling UAC says "not recommended", it doesn't say "never do that". That's the beauty of Windows. Millions of people use it with different software, settings and customization yet MS still manages to please a big portion of such diversity.

Comment: Problem was solved by using the latest version of Winrar application

Answer (score 3):

Even with the latest WinRAR I had this problem. The following worked for me:

- Open Windows Explorer (Windows +E)
- Type `%ProgramFiles%\WinRar`
- Right click on `WinRar.exe`
- Select *Properties*
- Go to the *Compatibility* tab
- Click the "Change settings for all user" button
- Uncheck everything
- Click Accept

Comment: Yep, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. open winrar folder, in program files(whether program files x86/x64)
2. double click on rareg.key to register it in registry and click ok
   worked for me :)

Comment: Are you sure you had the same problem as the poster to begin with?